# How event take its value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm starting to learn javascript and trying to understand how an event take its value.

I'm trying to get the `id` of an element by clicking on it and I get in it using:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", ev => console.log(ev));
```

I get a `MouseEvent` object on console where target key apparently get the id (confirm this too, I'm not sure).
But what I really don't understand is, how does MouseEvent object get converted as argument of that function.

Comment: Each of the various events call the registered event handler(s) and pass to that handler the appropriate event object that has been populated with the details of the event. You can find some details [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events)

Answer (score 0):

Check "srcElement" property of your MouseEvent, there is your id inside of it.